# PowerPoint VSTO Add-in - add a shape with a tag

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I would like to programatically add a shape into the current slide of PowerPoint in C# .NET

So, I have created a VSTO Add-in with a ribbon which has a button "Add Shape".
When this button is clicked, the following code executes:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.AddShape(
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 10, 20);
```

When this code executes, it correctly adds a rectangle shape into the current slide.

I would like to modify this shape later (for example; change it's width). To be able to do this, I read somewhere that the shape should have a unique identifier and this can be achieved using a `Tag`?

If so, how do you add a shape and set a tag on the newly added shape, so that I can manipulate it later?

Also, how do you iterate through the collection of shapes on the current slide, so that you can check the tag of the shape to see if that's the one I want to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .AddShape method can return a reference to the shape you've just added.
You'll want to do that for simplicity's sake.

The shape has a .Tags object
The .Tags object has an .Add method

So assuming a reference to the shape in oShape, you can do (again in VBA, you'll have to translate):

```
oShape.Tags.Add "MyTagName", "MyTagValue"
```

For more information and an example (VBA) function that returns a reference to a shape with a given tag value, you can visit this page on my PPT FAQ site:

Working with Tags (and a bit about Functions)
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00815_Working_with_Tags_-and_a_bit_about_Functions-.htm

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug; but when I use `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.AddShape` to add a shape, I can't seem to get any intelliSesnse to show up. Otherwise I would have seen that it returned a reference. Is there a different way to add a shape to current slide?

Comment: Also, what type do i use when I add a shape and get the reference? I tried  this `var newShape = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.AddShape(...);` and if i typed `newShape.` I am not getting anything back from intellisense. If I put the carret on `AddShape` method and press `f12`, I get this error: `Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret.`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with the dot.net stuff.  I don't need it, don't use it.

Comment: Everybody knows that dot.net guys are smarter than us VBA dweebs.  I figured you'd get it!  ;-)   A useful suggestion, though:  when PPT isn't making much sense, start it, press Alt+F11 to start the VBA IDE, then F9 to open the Object Browser.  It's a good way to find out quickly what object/methods/properties are available.

Comment: Thanks again. That's definitely useful.